# Приоритет подключения js и css файлов YII1

Tags: php, jquery, yii, bootstrap

Например, есть 3 js-файла:

- jquery.js
- bootstrap.js
- script.js

jquery.js и bootstrap.js подключены в методе `beforeAction()` класса `Controller`, который наследует `CController`.

Подключаю так:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('path/to/script', CClientScript::POS_END);
```

В классе `TaskController` (наследует `Controller`) в методе `init()` подключаю script.js.

Тут тоже подключаю так:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('path/to/script', CClientScript::POS_END);
```

В итоге файлы подключаются в такой последовательности: 
 - script.js
 - jquery.js 
 - bootstrap.js

А мне нужно так:

- jquery.js
- bootstrap.js
- script.js

**Что я хочу в идеале:** 
Иметь некий инструмент, с помощью которого при подключении скриптов я бы мог указывать их приоритет, например, с помощью числа (1, 2, 100).

P.S. Пытался написать свой компонент `ClientAsset`, который бы хранил все подключаемые файлы у себя, а в конце просто сортировал по приоритету и подключал через `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript()`. Но я не понимаю как мне сделать, чтобы в конце работы вызвать нужный метод этого класса... Запутался...

Comment: что-то больше смахивает на yii1

Comment: Да, действительно, исправил. Есть идеи по вопросу?